# Quick app install

Tags: installation, quickly

Is there a way to install apps in ubuntu 12.04?
What I am looking for is something like an *.msi file for windows. If there isn't, then is there a way to enable all software resources so that you could just install an app by clicking on the install button in the SC? I am not concerned about viruses, as I can just wipe the partition and re install ubuntu, no personal files are stored on the computer.

Answer (score 1):

The MSI Equivalent in Ubuntu is a .deb package.

You will need your password regardless in Ubuntu Software Center. It will function just like you found it in the Software Center, but the package would exist wherever you downloaded it to.

I personally use the Synaptic Package Manager as I can search for plenty of packages and select multiples to install then finally apply the settings.

`sudo apt-get install synaptic` in the Terminal(Ctrl+Alt+T) to install the synaptic package manager.

If you aren't afraid of the terminal, however, `sudo apt-get install [common package name here]` is exactly what you are looking for.

HOWEVER, it is important to note that certain premium packages provided by the Software Center will not be available. I.E. You may not find Steam in Synaptic